# Error on Container inside referenceContainer checkout.cart.methods

Tags: magento2, layout, xml

I have a problem with a custom block inside the container Checkout Cart methods.

I have add this code on checkout_cart_index.xml on my theme.

```
<referenceContainer name="checkout.cart.methods">
     <container name="cart-ship" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="info" output="1">
      ( ... block cms ...)
     </container>
  </referenceContainer>
```

This code generate a error:

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid Method: cart-ship

There are a reason for this error? If i declare a block directly on referenceContainer work correctly..